# Use of peri- prefix where sub- and super- are commonly used (Or, is periterranean valid?)

Tags: single-word-requests, prefixes

While trying to construct a description of the various train networks of London, I wanted to use the word *periterranean* to mean "close to the ground", with reference to *subterranean* (under the ground) and, I suppose, *superterranean* (above the ground).

I am aware that *superterranean* would typically cover both the "on the ground" and "above the ground" cases, but I wanted a word to distinguish, say, the Docklands Light Railway (much of which runs on raised tracks) from the London Overground (much of which runs on surface tracks). Of course, both should be distinguished from the London Underground, even though 55% of the Underground is, in fact, above ground.

Extensive Google searches failed to bring up anything of relevance, so my question is this: Are there any examples of *periterranean* used in the context I have described, and, if not, what would be a more appropriate word?

Comment: How 'bout unadorned *terranean*? It's not as self-explanatory as periterranean, but it doesn't require you to coin a new word, either.

Comment: @DanBron Actually, I rather like that. It hadn't occurred to me to use the word without any prefix at all.

Comment: What's wrong with the usual 'surface'?

Comment: Using *surface* and *elevated* might require less explanation.

Comment: I don't mind the explanation; I was looking for a moderately obscure or arcane way to phrase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that would be a bad choice. Greek *peri-* means "around, about", which is not what you want. Cf. *perimeter, perihelion, periphery,* etc. In Latin, the prefix used to indicate "near" would be *ad-*, which assimilates to *at-* before a *t-.* So **atterranean** would be properly formed and somewhat near your intended meaning.

Comment: I hadn't considered the origins; now that you mention peri- being Greek, I agree that it isn't what I want. In this case, **aterranean** works nicely.

Comment: Of course, it helps if I can type it properly, so I suppose I meant that **atterranean** works nicely.

Comment: @Andrew: Haha you can do it!

Answer (score 2):

It's generally considered a bit of a faux pas to mix Latin and Greek prefixes and words.
*Sub-* is Latin whilst *peri-* is greek.

They also mean different things; *sub-* means below and *peri-* means near/around.

A better alternative might be juxta-terranean?

Comment: I know that they mean different things. I wanted to use *peri-* for near-the-ground.

Comment: Juxta- would be the nearest Latin prefix I'm aware of to peri-. Admittedly though "Juxta-terranian" isn't the most eloquent thing you'll every hear.

Comment: It's three years on, but I can't resist noting the use of the **French** loan phrase _faux pas_ in an **English** discussion about mixing **Latin** and **Greek**. Kudos (seriously), @Niall, or should I say κῦδος, for such impressively polyglottal _chutzpah_. :-)

Comment: @tkp well, as any good neighbour will tell you - it's ok to borrow things, so long as you don't break them.